# SQLAlchemy connection hangs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
def get_engine():
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://...my_conn_string...', echo=True)
    return engine

def generic_execute(sql):
    db = get_engine()
    connection = db.connect()
    connection.execute(sql)
```

The code above executes the query properly but appears to hang infinitely.

How does one properly "close" or "kill" this connection? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the connection needs to be closed as stated by the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#basic-usage).

So after you are done executing the sql query you need to call:

```
connection.close()
```

Also if you are done with the engine `db` you can call `db.dispose()` to clean everything.